# Could privacy friendly open source OS/software be made for most tech products?

Tags: big-data, security, open-source, privacy

This is related to open source, but somewhat a new topic here that I hope you will contribute to in the discussion.

Many are tired of getting their privacy invaded by Google and all companies who take your data with and without consent. Would it not be great if there was an alternative?

**Would it be possible to for instance:**

- To install an app/software that denies any data going from for instance your smartwatch to Samsung, so they can't sell your data? Or from Google Nest to Google?
- If this is not possible, could you delete everything on for instance a Google Nest or smartwatch, collaborate on building open-source operating systems so that the product works and does not give away personal data?

The legality could be an issue, but one can argue that when major companies either steal data or take data with consent, you should react to protect the public interests. The Cambridge Analytica scandal should have taught everyone by now that our privacy and data should be better protected. And the companies selling our data to the highest bidders are not someone who should have the power of our data in their hands.

I'm new to IT, so these are questions I cannot find answers to online or here at the forum. If this discussion proves that either of the options can be realized, then I could be interested in bringing any of these ideas to life.